# How to custom simpleType by using JaxB Like Restriction

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, restriction

i tried some Annotations But are not worked for me I thinks all of them *Deprecated*?

- **@digits**
- **@Pattern(....)**

```xml
<xs:simpleType name="TypeNote">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
        <xs:minInclusive value="10"></xs:minInclusive>
        <xs:maxInclusive value="20"></xs:maxInclusive>
        <xs:totalDigits value="4"></xs:totalDigits>
        <xs:fractionDigits value="2"></xs:fractionDigits>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Comment: You are talking about deprecated annotations. Could you give more context ? Is a solution using annotations is acceptable for you ?

Comment: I belive, in your Java code. `xs:minInclusive`, `xs:maxInclusive`, `xs:totalDigits`, and `xs:fractionDigits` are depricated or non-existing. You need to perform the validation manually in your Java code. Please give a bit more description what you are doing, as it may help others to find a better solution for you https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlType.html